# My footer won't align vertically

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make my `li` elements stay on the same line but they won't (they are aligning horizontally but that's about it)

Code is as follows:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="coisas"
      class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
          <ul class="col-6">
            <li class="col-1"><img src="icon-behance.png"></li>
            <li class="col-1"><img src="icon-behance.png"></li>
            <li class="col-1"><img src="icon-behance.png"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <div id="nothing"
      class="col-6">
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#coisas {
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  size: 50%;
  left: 0;
  padding-left: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}
#nothing {
  size: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but Bootstrap `col`'s should always be inside `row`..

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="coisas" class="col-6">
                <ul class="row list-unstyled">
                    <li class="col-1"><img src="//placehold.it/40"></li>
                    <li class="col-1"><img src="//placehold.it/40"></li>
                    <li class="col-1"><img src="//placehold.it/40"></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="nothing" class="col-6">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

http://codeply.com/go/ArVyBK4VU5

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option

```
#coisas ul li{
  display:inline;
}
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vmdYNg

Answer (score 0):

The float property specifies whether or not a box (an element) should float.
If you float the `li` elements to the left, they will lineup in same line.So to put them on one line you can use this:

```
#coisas ul li{
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
}
```

The `list-style-type:none;` property is only for removing the bullet points of the list items.

You can learn more about the css `float` property here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @RBT context added.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your problem, resolved it now you can check it here!

```
#coisas ul li{
  display:inline;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/VijayVj7/3xbwh4qh/)